# Creating a program that asks the user for a name and creates 10 files with names serialized using C

Tags: c, string, file

I'm trying to figure out file handling and I'm just not able to think of a way to do this. Any help would be appreciated!
Need something like this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char string[10];
        FILE *fp1;

        printf("Enter the string");
        scanf("%s", string);

        fp1 = fopen(string, "w");


        /---- 


        fclose(fp1);
        return 0;
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to get the serialized files :(
I thought I could make 10 FILE* fptr's and then do it but idk how to get the serialized part

Bruno's solution seems to be working.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
        char string[10];
        FILE* fp[10];


        printf("Enter the string");
        scanf("%s", string);

        char fn[sizeof(string)+8];


        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
                sprintf(fn, "%s%d", string, i);
                if((fp[i] = fopen(fn, "w")) == 0)
                        printf("Cannot open %s\n", fn);
        }


        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
                fclose(fp[i]);
        }
        return 0;
This seems to be working. Thanks
```

Should be something like this:

Input:

```
Give me a name: Test
```

Output:

```
Created Test1.txt, Test2.txt, Test3.txt, .... Test10.txt
```

Comment: Where are you having trouble? Getting user input? Creating the file names? Creating the files?

Comment: What have you tried? Post your attempts so far.

Comment: Please show us what you tried and how it failed. Please read [ask] page!! Also: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: to create text file, just look into fopen function that opens on mode "w". that should open new file with a specific name you give it

Comment: Getting the user input isn't the problem. I can just input a string from the user, and we can use fptr = fopen(name, "w"); if I'm not wrong. I'm just unable to do the name1, name2, name3.... things :(

Comment: As mentioned in the first comment, see [sprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). `char filename[256]; sprintf(filename, "%s%d.txt", user_input, the_number);`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp if you are using a char[255] use `snprintf` so you dont stack overflow yourself

Comment: @NeXT so look at my answer, ask me if something is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do something like that

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define N 10

int main()
{
  assert((N >= 0) && (N <= 999)); /* check the value of N if it is changed */

  char base[10]; /* the base name of the files */
  FILE *fp[N]; /* to save the file descriptors */

  printf("Enter the base name:");
  if (scanf("%9s", base) != 1)
    // EOF
    return -1;

  char fn[sizeof(base) + 7]; /* will contains the name of the files */

  for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
    sprintf(fn, "%s%d.txt", base, i+1);
    if ((fp[i] = fopen(fn, "w")) == 0)
      printf("cannot open %s\n", fn);
  }

  /* ... */

  for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
    if (fp[i] != NULL)
      fclose(fp[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I size *fn* to allow 7 more characters than *base* because of the limitation about N (*assert*) allowing 3 digits for the number more the 4 characters of ".txt"

`scanf("%9s", ..)` allows to enter the base name limiting it to 9 characters, compatible with the size of *base* (10 to also have place for the null character ending the string)

*sprintf* is like a *printf* but except to print the result on *stdout* that one is put in the string being the first argument. Note that rewrites each time *base* in *fn* for nothing, this can be optimized.

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra f.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo aze*
aze*
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter the base name:aze
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo aze*
aze10.txt aze1.txt aze2.txt aze3.txt aze4.txt aze5.txt aze6.txt aze7.txt aze8.txt aze9.txt
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Before the execution `echo aze*` produces `aze*` because there is no file with a name starting by *aze*, after the execution `aze*` indicates the created files which are the expected

Comment: This does seem to be working.. but can you try to tell me what's wrong with my code? I just seem to be making a single file with a random name: for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
                sprintf(fn, "s%d", string, i);
                if((fp[i] = fopen(fn, "w")) == 0)
                        printf("Cannot open %s\n", fn);
        }

Comment: @NeXT in `sprintf(fn, "s%d", string, i)` you missed a % , must be `sprintf(fn, "%s%d", string, i)`, because of that you set the string to 's' then (a part of) the address of _string_

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working!

Comment: @NeXT you welcome, happy coding